# Online image failed to be loaded in my html using Chrome

Tags: image, cross-origin-read-blocking

This is the URL of the image.

https://holmesglen.edu.au/Holmesglen/media/Promo-banner/Testtf.jpg

And I am using it on my own website using <img> tag.

```
<img src="https://holmesglen.edu.au/Holmesglen/media/Promo-banner/Testtf.jpg">
```

Test result:

1. Google Chrome failed to load the image. The response is an HTTP 302, with "location: /my.policy"
2. MS Edge failed with the same behaviour as Google Chrome
3. Firefox loads the image fine
4. Postman (with all request headers as Google Chrome) loads the image fine

My questions are:

1. What is the cause of the failure on Google Chrome and MS Edge?
2. Why the results are different in Firefox and Postman?

By the way, my goal is not about successfully display the image, but to figure out the reason why.

Thanks.

Comment: The HTTP 302 makes me feel that the control is on the server side. But if the control is on server, why firefox & postman could display it.

Comment: Edit your question to add the error message you get in Chrome's console. It's likely a CORB error: the MIME type of the response likely isn't compatible with the `img` tag.